# Informal way to say "I am answerable to ..."

Tags: phrase-usage, synonyms

What is another, more informal way to say *I am answerable to [somebody]* as in the sentence:

> I am answerable only to President.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Answerable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/answerable) to someone means being accountable to someone (or responsible to someone for something), in the sense that you must answer for your actions, if someone asks.

I don't know that there's a more informal direct alternative (e.g. single word substitution). The sentence you cited (I'd add "the")

> I am answerable only to the President.

is basically saying that the subject ("I") doesn't have to explain his/her actions to anyone but the President. In fact, that might be one possible answer:

> I don't have to explain my actions to anyone but the President.

Except that sounds kind of [snotty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snotty) and immature. The word *answerable* somehow seems to avoid that.

I'm not sure that *answerable* is really that formal, however. It's just one of those idioms used in the context of organizational responsibility.